# dplyr::recode Why does pipe generate error?

Tags: r, dplyr, pipe, recode

If I use recode in a pipe, I get an error:

```
df <-  df %>%
  recode(unit, .missing="g")
```

> Error in UseMethod("recode") : no applicable method for 'recode'
>   applied to an object of class "c('tbl_df', 'tbl', 'data.frame')"

If I pull it out of the pipe, it works fine:

```
df$unit <- recode(df$unit, .missing="g")
```

Any ideas why?  I'd like to stay in the pipe if possible.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

An equivalent of the baseR solution in `dplyr` is to use it inside `mutate`:

```
df %>%
    mutate(unit = recode(unit, .missing="g"))
```

Directly chaining `recode` after `%>%` will pass the data frame to `recode` as the first argument, which doesn't agree with `recode`'s parameters. The first argument `.x` needs to be a vector; unlike some other `dplyr` functions `recode` doesn't use some non-standard evaluation magic to interpret `unit` as the column with that name in `df`. Most functions designed for direct use with the pipe have a data frame as their first argument and their output. You can read more about `magrittr` and how the pipe works [here](http://magrittr.tidyverse.org).